# Remove Duplicates - Ignoring Column

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a macro that selects all cells with date and then Removes the Duplicates while not considering Columns J or K.

I started just trying to get VBA to consider Column A only (starting with A3, Row 1 and 2 are title rows) to test.

```
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim LastColumn As Long
Dim StartCell As Range

Set sht = Worksheets("Credit Time")
Set StartCell = Range("A3")

lastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, StartCell.Column).End(xlUp).Row
LastColumn = sht.Cells(StartCell.Row, sht.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

sht.Range(StartCell, sht.Cells(lastRow, LastColumn)).Select
RemoveDuplicates Column:=1 Header:=xlNo
```

If I edit our the `RemoveDup...` line, all the data is selected perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Construct your array of columns to consider when removing duplicates on the fly while discarding columns J and K.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
    Dim lastRow As Long, LastColumn As Long, StartRow As Long
    Dim i As Long, arr As Variant

    With Worksheets("Credit Time")

        StartRow = 3
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastColumn = .Cells(StartRow, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        ReDim arr(0 To LastColumn - 3)
        For i = 1 To LastColumn
            If i <> Range("J:J").Column And i <> Range("K:K").Column Then
                arr(i - 1 + Int(i > Range("K:K").Column) * 2) = i
            End If
        Next i

        'arr = Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 12)

        With .Range(.Cells(StartRow, "A"), .Cells(lastRow, LastColumn))
            .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=(arr), Header:=xlNo
        End With
    End With
End Sub
```

The `(arr)` is not a typo; it is necessary for vba to recognize the variant array as an array of column index numbers.